# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, c, matlab, visual-c++, mex

I'm fresh in c++ and I'm facing a problem in including C++ code in Matlab C Mex-file.

I have 5 files: `RTIFederate.h`, `RTIFederate.cpp`, `RTIFedAmb.cpp`, `RTIFedAmb.h`, `RTI3.cpp`. `RTI3.cpp` contains the MEX modules. I'm getting the following errors while compiling with MEX command and libraries:

```
Creating library C:\Users\Nudel\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_DBx_sv\templib.x and object
   C:\Users\Nudel\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_DBx_sv\templib.exp 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class rti1516e::ObjectInstanceHandle   DistributedParametersLine" (?DistributedParametersLine@@3VObjectInstanceHandle@rti1516e@@A) referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * IEC_Model" (?IEC_Model@@3PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * IEC_Attribute" (?IEC_Attribute@@3PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class rti1516e::ObjectInstanceHandle PowerResource" (?PowerResource@@3VObjectInstanceHandle@rti1516e@@A) referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class rti1516e::AttributeHandle * _classattribute" (?_classattribute@@3PAVAttributeHandle@rti1516e@@A) referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall RTIFedAmb::RTIFedAmb(void)" (??0RTIFedAmb@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall RTIFederate::run(void)" (?run@RTIFederate@@QAEXXZ) 
RTI3.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals 

 C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'RTI3.mexw32' failed
```

My `RTI3.cpp` has the following piece of code:

```
#include "RTIFederate.cpp"
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    RTIFederate *c = (RTIFederate*) ssGetPWork(S)[0];   
    // Lê a porta de entrada correspondente
    time_T offset = ssGetOffsetTime(S,0);
    time_T timeOfNextHit = ssGetT(S) + offset  ;
    ssSetTNext(S, timeOfNextHit);
    for(int_T i=0;i<NUM_INPUTS;i++) { 
        int *dims = ssGetInputPortDimensions(S, i);
        int frameSize = dims[0]; // Tamanho do campo (se for trifasico sera 3 , por ex
        int numChannels = dims[1];
        if((ssGetInputPortWidth(S,i)<1) ||(ssGetInputPortWidth(S,i)>1)|| (frameSize>1)) {
            InputRealPtrsType uPtrs = ssGetInputPortRealSignalPtrs(S, i); 
            real_T               *y = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,i);
            int_T             width = ssGetOutputPortWidth(S,i);
            mexPrintf("%s%d%s%s%d\n","Num da entrada ->",i," ","Num largura > ",width);                      
            for (int_T j=0;j<width;j++){   
                *y++ =*uPtrs[j]; 
                mexPrintf("%s%u%s\n","IEC_Model[",i,"]--",IEC_Attribute[i].c_str());
                if(IEC_Model[i].compare("DistributedParametersLine")!=0) {
                    if(IEC_Attribute[i].compare("Voltage")) {
                        mexPrintf("%s%u%s%f\n","Voltage[",j,"]-->",*uPtrs[j]);
                        c->AtualizaValoresdeAtributos(DistributedParametersLine,_classattribute[0],*uPtrs[j],timeOfNextHit);
                    } else if(IEC_Attribute[i].compare("Current")) {
                        mexPrintf("%s%u%s%f\n","Current[",j,"]-->",*uPtrs[j]);
                        c->AtualizaValoresdeAtributos(DistributedParametersLine,_classattribute[0],*uPtrs[j],timeOfNextHit);
                    } 
                } // end if IEC_Model
                mexPrintf("%s%f\n","Avanco de tempo1->",timeOfNextHit);
            } // end for
        } else {
            double *u1=(double *) ssGetInputPortSignal(S, i);
            real_T *y1 = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,i);              
            (*y1) =(*u1); //copia entrada para saida
            mexPrintf("%s%f\n","Avanco de tempo2->",timeOfNextHit); 
            c->AtualizaValoresdeAtributos(PowerResource,_classattribute[0],*u1,timeOfNextHit);       
        } // end else
    } // end for i
}

/* Function: mdlTerminate  */

static void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)
{
    char *buf;
    size_t buflen;
    int status;

    buflen = mxGetN((ssGetSFcnParam(S, 2)))*sizeof(mxChar)+1 ; // read 3rd param
    buf = (char *)mxMalloc(buflen); //alloc mem
    status = mxGetString((ssGetSFcnParam(S, 2)), buf,(mwSize)buflen);

    ssGetPWork(S)[0] = (void *) new RTIFederate; // store new C++ object in the
    RTIFederate *c = (RTIFederate *) ssGetPWork(S)[0];
    c->InterpretaArqMDL(buf);  // Rotina que trata da interpretacao dos objetos da norma IEC 61968
    c->run(); 
    ...
}
```

On top of `RTIFederate.cpp` I have declared the following:

```
#include "RTIFedAmb.h"
#include "RTIFederate.h"
```

and in the file `RTIFederate.h` I declared:

```
class RTIFederate
{
public:
    RTIambassador *rtiamb;
    RTIFedAmb     *fedamb;

    // variables //

    ObjectClassHandle  _ClassObject[300];
    AttributeHandle  _classattribute[300];
    string IEC_Model[29],IEC_Attribute[20];//  

    // public methods //

    RTIFederate();
    virtual ~RTIFederate();
    ...
}

extern ObjectClassHandle  _ClassObject[300];
extern AttributeHandle  _classattribute[300];  
extern AttributeHandleSet  attributeSet[300];  

extern ObjectInstanceHandle ProtectedSwitch,Recloser,ThreePhaseBreaker,ACLineSegment,DistributedParametersLine;

extern RTIambassador *rtiamb;
extern RTIFedAmb     *fedamb;
```

Also there is a piece of code in `RTIFedAmb.h:`

```
//methods
RTIFedAmb();
virtual ~RTIFedAmb() throw();
```

Can anyone help me to explain what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to include c-lib in your c ++ project. That's fine but you should note one thing: c ++ differs a bit from c. And you found a good illustration.
c ++ "deforms" function names in lib while c does not. Nevertheless you still can use c libraries. Do it so:

```
     extern "C" ObjectClassHandle  _ClassObject[300];
     extern "C" AttributeHandle  _classattribute[300];  
     extern "C" AttributeHandleSet  attributeSet[300];  

     extern "C" ObjectInstanceHandle ProtectedSwitch,Recloser,ThreePhaseBreaker,ACLineSegment,DistributedParametersLine;

     extern "C" RTIambassador *rtiamb;
     extern "C" RTIFedAmb     *fedamb;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Interesting. I was trying another thing . As I have a pointer (c) to RTIFederate I changed the line c->AtualizaValoresdeAtributos(DistributedParametersLine,_classattribute[0],*uPtrs[j],timeOfNextHit);  to  c->AtualizaValoresdeAtributos(c->DistributedParametersLine,c->_classattribute[0],*uPtrs[j],timeOfNextHit);

Comment: and it compiled without the previous errors. But I still have a link problem with LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall RTIFedAmb::RTIFedAmb(void)" (??0RTIFedAmb@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall RTIFederate::run(void)" (?run@RTIFederate@@QAEXXZ)  which I was able to find the answer. Any idea ?

Comment: by the way I changed to extern "C"but I still get the same errors. when I use c->DistributedParametersLine, the compilation goes ok.