# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall

Tags: c++, linker-errors

As I had previously sent some questions about [LNK 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872568/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol), I'm facing the same problem with a piece of code that I don't understand what is going on:

RTIFederate.cpp

```
#include "RTIFedAmb.h"
#include "RTIFederate.h"

....

this->fedamb = new RTIFedAmb(); <- ERROR ! LNK 2019
```

RTIFedAmb.h

```
class RTIFedAmb : public NullFederateAmbassador
{
public:
    // methods //
    RTIFedAmb();
    virtual ~RTIFedAmb() throw();
}
```

File RTIFederate.h

```
class RTIFederate
{
public:
    RTIambassador *rtiamb;
    RTIFedAmb     *fedamb;
}
```

RTIFedAmb.cpp

```
#include "RTIFedAmb.h"
using namespace rti1516e;
using namespace std;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                       CONSTRUCTORS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
RTIFedAmb::RTIFedAmb()
{

}

RTIFedAmb::~RTIFedAmb() throw()
{
}
```

Can anyone help me with this error ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Why is this tagged matlab?

Comment: `What am I missing ?` - linker answered already.

Comment: @kotlomoy I've found that asking a compiler questions to be a futile endeavor.

Comment: @user2169880 post the full error report. What you posted in title is truncated

Comment: Here follows the error message:  Creating library C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_22fLSJ\templib.x and object C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_22fLSJ\templib.exp 
RTI3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall RTIFedAmb::RTIFedAmb(void)" (??0RTIFedAmb@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall RTIFederate::run(void)" (?run@RTIFederate@@QAEXXZ) 
RTI3.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
 
  C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'RTI3.mexw32' failed.

Comment: Ok but do you know can I compile few CPP files with MEX command ? There is one CPP file that contains Matlab methods that calls methods developed in another CPP file. Do I need to take the include and compile everything together ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see in your original question that RTI3.cpp is #including "RTIFederate.cpp".  This is not recommended.  After separating your source files for compilation, if you still have link errors, I'd recommend using the VS tools `dumpbin.exe` and `undname.exe`.  Dumpbin can show you where your RTIFedAmb constructor is both defined and referenced (obj files), as well as revealing any decoration issues (calling convention, linkage, etc).  Undname can then help you understand and fix these discrepancies.